# Converting images to DPI (Dots per Inch) sizes

Tags: android, graphics, photoshop, image-resizing, dpi

I am having a big trouble in resizing my images for Android image sizes, `ldpi` (120 dpi), `mdpi`(160 dpi), `hdpi`(240dpi), `xhdpi`(320 dpi) and `nodpi` using Photoshop, because I don't know how to convert my images to these size. As you know, Photoshop has no DPI stuff to work with. So, what I actually need is to convert my images to `ldpi`,`mdpi`,`hdpi` and `xhdpi` sizes using Photoshop.

[image]

So, how can I convert these images to the Android deserved sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Illustrator? The psd files can also be worked with it.

You could also use Inkscape or other free tools.

Check this: http://envyandroid.com/archives/271/easiest-way-to-create-android-icons

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there in your screenshot. Photoshop uses **Pixels/Inch** which is the same as DPI (well mostly, anyway).

To achieve what you are trying to do, simply alter the **Pixels/Inch** in the `Image Size` dialog to your DPI value - start with 320dpi, since shrinking images will look better than enlarging them. After altering the value you will notice that your width and height values (**Pixel Dimensions**) are changed, change them back to the desired resolution for your 320dpi image (make sure that you use a sufficiently large resolution for 320dpi).

Now create your image for this resolution. Once you are complete, open the `Image Size` dialog again. Now all you need to do is alter the **Pixels/Inch** value to the remaining DPI values (240, 160, 120) and your image will be scaled down (notice how the width and height for Pixel Dimensions will get smaller with each decrease in DPI).

If you have no idea about the starting resolution you can use the width and height under **Document Size** to set the actual resolution. For example, the Nexus 4 is a 320ppi device (mostly) and has a screen size of 4.7" (5.27x x 2.70x), so if you use a width of 2.635" and a height of 1.35" it should cover 1/4 of it's screen (half of width and half of height).